# Crystal Report Text Postion Change After Run My Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i just want to know how to set crystal report format after run the crystal run the crystal text position change how fix it please me...
[image]

As you can see in this "category and term" position change.. what is the issue. crystal report text position change after run.

Comment: Is it displaying properly when you run the preview from the Crystal report file?

Comment: yes display properly in crystal report file